# Get shell input as string, not list

Tags: python

If I have the command:

```
$ /file.py item 2
```

Doing `sys.argv` would give me:

```
['/file.py', 'item 2']
```

Is there a method to get the exact text inputted, without doing `' '.join(sys.argv)` ?

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware. This seems like [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - could you explain a bit about why you need this?

Comment: ...also, `' '.join(sys.argv)` gives you an incorrect result -- consider `./yourprog foo bar` vs `./yourprog "foo bar"`.

Comment: ...if you _did_ want that, you'd need to use `pipes.quote(sys.argv)`, or `shlex.quote(sys.argv)` (depending on whether your target platform is Python 2.x or Python 3).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exact end-user input given *is never communicated from the shell to the program being run*. Assembling an argument vector is performed by the shell, and that vector -- and not the string from which it is built -- is passed as an argument to the `execve` system call.

Indeed, there may not exist a shell command at all -- think of the case where your script is invoked with `subprocess.call(['/file.py', 'item 2'], shell=False)`, or its equivalents in other languages.

Without modifying your shell to do something special (such as exporting the last command to an environment variable -- something which could be easily implemented with a `DEBUG` trap), there is no possible way to retrieve it.